# Magento 2.2.6 How to UPDATE attribute (Mass Action), don't REPLACE attribute that already exist?

Tags: magento2, attributes

All it is in the title of the topic.

I want to update product that already exist with different attributes.

it's impossible to me to add a bulk operation because when I use the product update of magento2 it replace the attribute that already exist...

For example:

```
Product 1: Attribute A
Product 2: Attribute B
```

I want simply add attribute C to product 1 and 2 like this :

```
Product 1: Attribute A,C
Product 2: Attribute B,C
```

When I use Update product of Magento when I only check Attribute C, the result is:

```
Product 1: Attribute C
Product 2: Attribute C
```

Is it possible to UPDATE and don't replace the attributes ?

I hope I was clear !